# C# MethodeInfo Invoke

Tags: c#

Hey I'm getting error with this code:

```
public  void readCommand(string data)
    {
        string[] commandInfo = data.Split(':');
        string command = commandInfo[0];
        object[] @params = new object[commandInfo.Length-1];
        for(int i = 1;i<commandInfo.Length;i++)
        {
            @params[i - 1] = commandInfo[i];
        }

            if (commands.Contains(command))
            {
                try
                {
                    MethodInfo Minfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(command);
                    Minfo.Invoke(this, @params);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }

    }
```

I'm trying to invoke a method called ShowMes:

```
   private  void ShowMes(string par)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)par);
    }
```

what is wrong with that code ? because the invoke throws an Exception

"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: the code is very confusing to me... if you have access to this, as in this is the type you are wanting.... why cant you call the method off the class, instead of using reflection.... i mean you could do this with an if statement on commandInfo[0], reducing the need for reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetMethod` you're trying to use

> Searches for the public method with the specified name.

Your method is private, so you have to use [the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes `BindingFlags` argument

```
MethodInfo Minfo = this.GetType()
    .GetMethod(command, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Thank You I didn't notice Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to include `BindingFalgs` when getting non public methods.
I guess `Minfo` is null when you call invoke on it.

Modify your code like this:

```
MethodInfo Minfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(command,BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

As I see in your app function names are coming as commands, maybe it will be useful to use `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase` flag too.